# Is it possible to "apply" AR on stored images with ARCore?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

A professor suggested me the following idea:
While using ARCore, take a picture, take a snapshot of the structure (whatever it is) made by ARCore at that instant, and save both of them in a database. Then load them, so you can "re-apply" AR on that photo (of course, it would be as if camera is not moving). It's a little weird, but it makes sense, because that photo would be an instant of a video, and feature points would be related to that instant.
I was said it would be a process called "Augmenting Image", I saw this: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images/ but it's not precisely what I want.

Has somebody developed something similar, or at least, is that possible?

Comment: You can simply superimpose one image on top of another, using a photo editor or by rendering one on top of the other when displaying. I am guessing you want something more than this so maybe you can explain what you want beyond this?

Comment: Are you trying to use that snapshot image as a source of detected feature points? What purpose would that serve? What's the outcome that you're envisioning?

Comment: I want to store scenarios, so you can retrieve them later. For example, if your are an in home designer, you go to the client's home, do some AR stuff, and then you can save this scenario, so you can do other AR stuff later, without being in the client's home.